# Acceder a las propiedades de un word con C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-office, ms-word, interop

Buenas tardes,

Necesito leer las propiedades y valores de las mismas en un documento word, hasta ahora solo he conseguido acceder al nombre de las mismas pero no a su valor. 
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document oDoc;
object originalFormat = Missing.Value;
object routeDocument = Missing.Value;
object oMissing = Missing.Value;
object saveChanges = false;
object oDocAuthorProp;
Type typeDocAuthorProp;

        oWord.Visible = false;

        object oFalse = false;
        object filePath = @"C:\Users\Ales\Documents\PRUEBAS 40257.doc";

        try
        {

            oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(ref filePath, ref oMissing, ref oFalse, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
            ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

            oDoc.Activate();

            var oDocBuiltInProps = oDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties;
            Type typeDocBuiltInProps = oDocBuiltInProps.GetType();
            foreach (var item in oDocBuiltInProps)
            {
                string nombre = item.Name;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de C# usas? Pregunto porque la sentencia larga con `oWord.Documents.Open(...)` puede simplificarse bastante si usas por lo menos C# 4.

Comment: Pues estoy usando la version 4.5 del Framework, la verdad es que el código es un copy/paste en modo rápido y no me he parado a refactorizarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crea una clase de este tipo:

```
class type_archives
{
    string tipo, valor;

    public string Tipo
    {
        get
        {
            return tipo;
        }

        set
        {
            tipo = value;
        }
    }

    public string Valor
    {
        get
        {
            return valor;
        }

        set
        {
            valor = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Después, en el método donde buscas las propiedades agrega esto:

```
List<Clases.type_archives> archivos = new List<Clases.type_archives>();
foreach (var item in oDocBuiltInProps)
{
    try
    {
         Clases.type_archives archivo = new Clases.type_archives();
         archivo.Tipo = item.Name;
         archivo.Valor = item.Value;
         archivos.Add(archivo);
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: ¿Para qué es el `catch` vacío? Estoy seguro que tienes una buena razón, pero me parece un poco excesivo el que se ignore todo tipo de excepciones por igual.

Comment: Hay valores que no tienen la propiedad "Value" o "Name" y dan error, así que cuando pasa por esos valores simplemente los ignoro.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quede solamente en la propiedad Name y descarte la Value porque no me cuadraba el resultado.